# How to update single item in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to update the recyclerview item using following code snippet.

```
public void setItemToPostion(WatchListEpisodeBean watchListBean, int itemPosition) {
    this.watchListBean.add(itemPosition, watchListBean);
    notifyItemChanged(itemPosition);
}
```

It works fine. That's item at position updated with new data. But the problem is item cloned to its next position(appears in next position). I don't find what's wrong with my code.

This is appcompat & support design lib versions:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

Please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the adapter code where u r calling the above method.

Comment: got the answer Rahavendra... Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your item is clone because you are adding item.

Try to use `set` instead of `add` like this

```
public void setItemToPostion(WatchListEpisodeBean watchListBean, int itemPosition) {
    this.watchListBean.set(itemPosition, watchListBean);
    notifyItemChanged(itemPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply updating one part of the view, use the `notifyItemChanged()` instead of `notifiyDataSetChanged()`. The difference here has to do with **structural changes vs item changes**. This is on the android developers RecyclerView.Adapter documentation found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,%20int)).

Here is another tidbit on the differences between the two types of changes:

> There are two different classes of data change events, item changes
>   and structural changes. Item changes are when a single item has its
>   data updated but no positional changes have occurred. Structural
>   changes are when items are inserted, removed or moved within the data
>   set.

Answer (score -4):

Use `notifyDataSetChanged();` instead of `notifyItemChanged(itemPosition);`

Comment: Jinal Patel, could you please explain why?